# Inconsistent output for csv writer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write data in csv format to a file. The data I am writing is pairs of integers. The inconsistency is that when the number 10 is written, I get a comma between the "1" and the "0". This just happens for the number 10, not for 11 etc.

Code:

```
clocktimes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]

with open('testfile.csv', 'w') as tf:
    writer = csv.writer(tf)
    for hour in clocktimes:
        if hour in hourtimes:
            writer.writerow( str((hour)).split(',') + str((hourtimes[hour])).split(',') )
        else:
            writer.writerow( (str(hour)) + (str(0)) )
```

(hourtimes is a dictionary consisting of integers as keys and values)

Output file:
7,0
8,0
9,0
1,0,0
11,144
12,112
13,80

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to prevent this outcome?

Comment: What is the `hourtimes` variable?

Comment: You are passing a single string to writerow. The `row` in `writerow(row)` is supposed to be a _sequence_ of strings or numbers, according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects). Your line `writer.writerow( (str(hour)) + (str(0)) )` is treating the string as a list of characters, and writing them one by one to your CSV. Either don't use `writerow`, or pass it the correct data.

Comment: Let us know of the hourtimes variable

Comment: I clearly state that the hourtimes variable is a dictionary consisting of integers as keys and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Random Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6273251/random-davis)!
I READ THE DOCUMENTATION and experimented some further and came up with this solution:

```
for hour in clocktimes:
        if hour in hourtimes:
            data = [hour, hourtimes[hour]]
            writer.writerow(data)
        else:
            data = [hour, 0]
            writer.writerow(data)
```

The data to be written is added to an array which is accepted by the writerow() method. Output is now as I wanted which is:
...
7,0
8,0
9,0
10,0
11,144
12,112
13,80
...